# Unable to Locate selector.js File in Trailhead Lightning Web Component Module

Tags: lightning-web-components, trailhead

In the "Add Styles and Data to a Lightning Web Component" section of the Trailhead "Lightning Web Component Basics" module the lessons says to add code to "...the selector.js file in the project we’ve been working on..."

But nothing I've created in the module to that point has "selector" in its name. I feel like I'm missing something basic, but don't see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to [Add Styles and Data to a Lightning Web Component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/add-styles-and-data-to-a-lightning-web-component) then the requirement is pretty straightforward.

At some point in the Trail, you should have created an Lightning Web Component Bundle which is composed of the following resources:

- selector.html
- selector.js
- selector.css

the code is event titled with what resource you should be applying the code to, you should probably go back a few modules and re-read the requirements and what resources need to be created.

Comment: It is straightforward as @glls said. The downloaded app used in the module did in fact contain the files. I managed to miss them because they were in a subfolder that had not been used to that point.

Comment: awesome, assuming you were able to get pass this?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'd mark yours as the answer but it looks like I'd need more reputation...

Comment: You were right.